# Icons for templates

Tags: nautilus, icons, templates

I have some templates in my ~/Templates folder, but there is no icons in context menu for any of them except the default "Empty Document".

menus_have_icons is enabled

How to get/set them?[image]

Ubuntu 12.04

GNOME nautilus 3.4.2

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version ? What is your Nautilus version ? On Ubuntu 12.10 with the gnome3-ppa activated (so Nautilus 3.6), I have icons for my templates.

Comment: @remjg I have updated topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem has something to do with this [Nautilus bug](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=602909). If it's actually the case, your problem was resolved with [this commit](http://git.gnome.org/browse/nautilus/commit/?id=1a1fa464fd16f93d9a9fbb73b894f4f6c0a098f8) in August, so after Nautilus 3.4 was out.

Maybe if you report a bug in Launchpad, the solution will be backported in Precise (and maybe in Quantal for those who don't have the [gnome3 PPA](https://launchpad.net/~gnome3-team/+archive/gnome3) activated, someone has to check though) ?

Sorry, I can't help you more on this topic !